# Stop motion short involving a robot taking over other robots in an apocalyptic wasteland

Tags: story-identification, robots, animation, short-film, stop-motion-animation

I don't remember much from this animation but I remember it being around maybe 17 min and being made maybe in 2012.

It was set in some kind of apocalyptic wasteland. There was a scrap metal robot that takes over another light bulb looking robot that's drinking some kind of dark liquid.

Near the end it takes over some kind of giant white robot and it attacks some kind of airship with people on it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SciFi.SE! Could you please have a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and [edit] in any extra details you remember? Do you remember where you watched this? On YouTube, on TV?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 6):

*OMEGA* by Eva Franz and Andy Goralczyk

> Check out this fantastic example of stop-motion skill and creativity the short film called "Omega". The end of evolution awaits in a wasteland dominated by bizarre trash formations, dust and rock. From the scattered remains of a long forgotten culture an electric ecosystem rapidly evolves into the ultimate form of existence...
>
> The mechanical life form Ohm inhabits a bleak and devastated planet. The thousands of mechanical creatures of this world share a single cycle of energy. In this cycle, Ohm is a rogue element. His nature is to devour and absorb others. When one day a gargantuan foreign object appears in the skies. Drawn in by mysterious creatures of light, the Ohm tracks them across the planet, changing the known order of matter, time and space.

### The complete short film

Found with a search for `stop motion film robot predation`